# Split a complex file into a hash

Tags: ruby

I am running a command line program, called **Primer 3**. It takes an input file and returns data to standard output. I am trying to write a Ruby script which will accept that input, and put the entries into a hash.

The results returned are below. I would like to split the data on the '=' sign, so that the has would something like this:

```
{:SEQUENCE_ID => "example", :SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE => "GTAGTCAGTAGACNAT..etc", :SEQUENCE_TARGET => "37,21" etc }
```

I would also like to lower case the keys, ie:

```
 {:sequence_id => "example", :sequence_template => "GTAGTCAGTAGACNAT..etc", :sequence_target => "37,21" etc }
```

This is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts 'Primer 3 hash'

primer3 = {}
while line = gets do
  name, height = line.split(/\=/)
  primer3[name] = height.to_i
end

puts primer3
```

It is returning this:

```
Primer 3 hash
{"SEQUENCE_ID"=>0, "SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE"=>0, "SEQUENCE_TARGET"=>37, "PRIMER_TASK"=>0,     "PRIMER_PICK_LEFT_PRIMER"=>1, "PRIMER_PICK_INTERNAL_OLIGO"=>1,  "PRIMER_PICK_RIGHT_PRIMER"=>1, "PRIMER_OPT_SIZE"=>18, "PRIMER_MIN_SIZE"=>15, "PRIMER_MAX_SIZE"=>21, "PRIMER_MAX_NS_ACCEPTED"=>1, "PRIMER_PRODUCT_SIZE_RANGE"=>75, "P3_FILE_FLAG"=>1, "SEQUENCE_INTERNAL_EXCLUDED_REGION"=>37, "PRIMER_EXPLAIN_FLAG"=>1, "PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_PARAMETERS_PATH"=>0, "PRIMER_LEFT_EXPLAIN"=>0, "PRIMER_RIGHT_EXPLAIN"=>0, "PRIMER_INTERNAL_EXPLAIN"=>0, "PRIMER_PAIR_EXPLAIN"=>0, "PRIMER_LEFT_NUM_RETURNED"=>0, "PRIMER_RIGHT_NUM_RETURNED"=>0, "PRIMER_INTERNAL_NUM_RETURNED"=>0, "PRIMER_PAIR_NUM_RETURNED"=>0, ""=>0}
```

Data source

```
SEQUENCE_ID=example
SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE=GTAGTCAGTAGACNATGACNACTGACGATGCAGACNACACACACACACACAGCACACAGGTATTAGTGGGCCATTCGATCCCGACCCAAATCGATAGCTACGATGACG
SEQUENCE_TARGET=37,21
PRIMER_TASK=pick_detection_primers
PRIMER_PICK_LEFT_PRIMER=1
PRIMER_PICK_INTERNAL_OLIGO=1
PRIMER_PICK_RIGHT_PRIMER=1
PRIMER_OPT_SIZE=18
PRIMER_MIN_SIZE=15
PRIMER_MAX_SIZE=21
PRIMER_MAX_NS_ACCEPTED=1
PRIMER_PRODUCT_SIZE_RANGE=75-100
P3_FILE_FLAG=1
SEQUENCE_INTERNAL_EXCLUDED_REGION=37,21
PRIMER_EXPLAIN_FLAG=1
PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_PARAMETERS_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/primer3/2.3.4/bin/primer3_config/
PRIMER_LEFT_EXPLAIN=considered 65, too many Ns 17, low tm 48, ok 0
PRIMER_RIGHT_EXPLAIN=considered 228, low tm 159, high tm 12, high hairpin stability 22, ok 35
PRIMER_INTERNAL_EXPLAIN=considered 0, ok 0
PRIMER_PAIR_EXPLAIN=considered 0, ok 0
PRIMER_LEFT_NUM_RETURNED=0
PRIMER_RIGHT_NUM_RETURNED=0
PRIMER_INTERNAL_NUM_RETURNED=0
PRIMER_PAIR_NUM_RETURNED=0
=

$ primer3_core < example2 | ruby /Users/sean/Dropbox/bin/rb/read_primer3.rb
```

Comment: +1 for a well-formed, complete question, including what you have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts 'Primer 3 hash'

primer3 = {}
while line = gets do
  key, value = line.split(/=/, 2)
  primer3[key.downcase.to_sym] = value.chomp
end

puts primer3
```

Comment: One question: what is the ,2 doing here: line.split(/=/, 2)

Comment: @SeanGeneva limit the fields got from `split`, in case that the value part contains `=`.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here are a couple of purely-functional solutions. Both assume that you've already pulled your data from the file, e.g.

```
my_data = ARGF.read # read the file passed on the command line
```

This one feels sort of gross, but it is a (long) one-liner :)

```
hash = Hash[ my_data.lines.map{ |line|
  line.chomp.split('=',2).map.with_index{ |s,i| i==0 ? s.downcase.to_sym : s }
} ]
```

This one is two lines, but feels cleaner than using `with_index`:

```
keys,values = my_data.lines.map{ |line| line.chomp.split('=',2) }.transpose
hash = Hash[ keys.map(&:downcase).map(&:to_sym).zip(values) ]
```

Both of these are likely less efficient and certainly more memory-intense than your already-accepted answer; iterating the lines and slowly mutating your hash is the best way to go. These non-mutating variations are just a mental exercise.

---

Your final answer should use `ARGF` to allow filenames on the command line or via STDIN. I would write it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

module Primer3
  def self.parse( file )
    {}.tap do |primer3|
      # Process one line at a time, without reading it all into memory first
      file.each_line do |line|  
        key, value = line.chomp.split('=', 2)
        primer3[key.downcase.to_sym] = value
      end
    end
  end
end

Primer3.parse( ARGF ) if __FILE__==$0
```

This way you can either call the file from the command line, with or without STDIN, or you can `require` this file and use the module function it defines in other code.

Answer (score -1):

OK I have it (almost). The only problem is it is adding a \n at the end of each value.

```
puts 'Primer 3 hash'

primer3 = {}
while line = gets do
  key, value = line.split(/\=/)
  puts key
  puts value
  primer3[key.downcase] = value
end

puts primer3

{"sequence_id"=>"example\n",  "sequence_template"=>"GTAGTCAGTAGACNATGACNACTGACGATGCAGACNACACACACACACACAGCACACAGGTATTAGTGGGCCATTCGATCCCGACCCAAATCGATAGCTACGATGACG\n", "sequence_target"=>"37,21\n", "primer_task"=>"pick_detection_primers\n", "primer_pick_left_primer"=>"1\n", "primer_pick_internal_oligo"=>"1\n", "primer_pick_right_primer"=>"1\n", "primer_opt_size"=>"18\n", "primer_min_size"=>"15\n", "primer_max_size"=>"21\n", "primer_max_ns_accepted"=>"1\n", "primer_product_size_range"=>"75-100\n", "p3_file_flag"=>"1\n", "sequence_internal_excluded_region"=>"37,21\n", "primer_explain_flag"=>"1\n", "primer_thermodynamic_parameters_path"=>"/usr/local/Cellar/primer3/2.3.4/bin/primer3_config/\n", "primer_left_explain"=>"considered 65, too many Ns 17, low tm 48, ok 0\n", "primer_right_explain"=>"considered 228, low tm 159, high tm 12, high hairpin stability 22, ok 35\n", "primer_internal_explain"=>"considered 0, ok 0\n", "primer_pair_explain"=>"considered 0, ok 0\n", "primer_left_num_returned"=>"0\n", "primer_right_num_returned"=>"0\n", "primer_internal_num_returned"=>"0\n", "primer_pair_num_returned"=>"0\n", ""=>"\n"}
```

Comment: Add `.chomp` to value to remove newlines.

Comment: @SeanGeneva I did not downvote, but answers that do not fully match the question criteria are often downvoted. This answer, for example, uses `gets` instead of a file and uses strings instead of keys for symbols.